# Using API of Google Translate

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I'm trying to translate a paragraph through the Google Translate API from English to Hebrew

The paragraph is:
Get ready for a fun-filled family holiday in Gran Canaria. This Gran Canaria Family TUI Pass will help you get the most out of your holiday with access to seven family-friendly attractions across the island. Prepare to laugh, shout, and enjoy, all at a special discounted price.

The output comes out mixed with words in both English and Hebrew when I want the entire answer to be only in Hebrew.

I would appreciate your help on this matter

Currently my code looks like this:

```
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
import os
from collection import *


os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'googlekey.json'


def translate_paragraph(text):
    client = translate.Client()
    result = client.translate(text, target_language='he')
    return result['translatedText']


text = "Get ready for a fun-filled family holiday in Gran Canaria. This Gran Canaria Family TUI Pass will help you get the most out of your holiday with access to seven family-friendly attractions across the island. Prepare to laugh, shout, and enjoy, all at a special discounted price."

print(translate_paragraph(text))
```

The output look like this:

" התכוננו לחופשה משפחתית מהנה בגראן קנריה. כרטיס TUI משפחתי זה של Gran Canaria יעזור לכם להפיק את המרב מהחופשה שלכם עם גישה לשבע אטרקציות ידידותיות למשפחות ברחבי האי. תתכוננו לצחוק, לצעוק וליהנות, הכל במחיר מוזל במיוחד."

The output text now is English and Hebrew, **and I need only Hebrew without English.**

thanks to anyone who can help !!!

I tried to read the google translate documentation and search the internet and ChatGPT but I didn't get a suitable answer.

Comment: Aren't the English terms names? Should they really be translated? I don't speak Hebrew, but in e.g., English we would still use Barcelona or Spain (instead of España), even though we use Munich instead of München.

Comment: Did you look at the translation on translate.google.com? it's exactly the same as what the API returned. You can't get the API to return something that the product doesn't do. It is not keeping "English" and "Hebrew" words it is just not translating names.